# Can I use "I go to a Walmart" when I'm going to a particular store?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

We can say:
I like bmw (when I mean the brand)

But
I like a bmw (it means that I like a particular car)

Does it work the same with names of stores? For example
"I go to **a** Walmart" when I mean some particular store or not and only saying "I go to Walmart" is correct?

Comment: Yes, I go to a Tesco every Thursday. Note: BMW the car brand uses capital letters.

Comment: Yes. They’re going to build a Costco in our town, and that will be much more convenient for us than the Costco we’ve been shopping at.

Comment: You can say *I shop at [**a**] Walmart most weeks* with or without the article, and usually they'll mean exactly the same. *Sometimes*, including the article might more strongly imply I shop at a number of *different* Walmart stores, but that's nowhere near a "rule". On the other hand, *I shop at **the** Walmart most weeks* virtually *forces* you to understand that I always shop at the ***same*** store.

Answer (score 2):

It can be said. It gives the impression that you have picked one out but [you don't consider it important to specify which one for the listener](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_quantity_(content_length_and_depth)).

> — Do you know where you're getting the party supplies?
> — Yeah, I'm gonna go to a Walmart on my way home from work.

This is a little rarer than the normal "go to Walmart", which can paradoxically mean either (a) it doesn't matter which one:

> Millions of Americans go to Walmart every day to shop for their basic needs.

or (b) there's exactly one that could be relevant, e.g. the only one in your town:

> I'm going to Walmart. Back in five minutes. Need anything?

Finally, note that not all verbs work like this. You can *go* to Walmart or *shop* at Walmart, but "*find* Walmart" sounds strange in most contexts — you "find *a* Walmart".

Comment: Though maybe the only trouble with "find Walmart" is that it would rarely mean a specific store. It seems fine in "I'm lost in this huge mall area, but if I find Walmart, I'll have my bearings again."

Comment: @aschepler Right, yeah. I was also thinking of a scavenger hunt item or something. "Did you find Walmart? I'm still looking for Costco."

Comment: +1.  "*a* Walmart" could also mean 'Walmart, not some other chain".  "You can find that at the local hardware store. --I know, but I'm going to a Walmart. I have a coupon for half off."